# Regex match, insert string data to SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, regex, string

I want to insert the data/string from the Regex match, to an table in my SQL database.

Here is the example of the code that I using.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.Data;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace AutoApp_Win32Server
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1,0\n\n");
            Console.WriteLine("1,0");

            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlDocument doc1 = web.Load("http://brandstofprijzen.info/?postcode=&plaats=8801&afstand=25&brandstof=Diesel&zoeken=Zoeken");

            HtmlNodeCollection tables = doc1.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/center/table");
            HtmlNodeCollection rows = tables[13].SelectNodes(".//tr");

            string makeSpace = " ";

            for (int i = 1; i < rows.Count; ++i)
            {
                HtmlNodeCollection cols = rows[i].SelectNodes(".//td");

                string nawhtml = cols[0].InnerHtml;
                string brandstof = cols[1].InnerText;
                string prijs = cols[2].InnerText;
                string datum = cols[3].InnerText;

                Regex match1 = new Regex(@"<b>\s*(.+?)\s*</b><br>");
                Match naamtankstation = match1.Match(nawhtml);
                Console.WriteLine("Naam         : " + naamtankstation.Groups[1].Value);



                Regex match2 = new Regex(@"</b><br>\s*(.+?)\s*<br>");
                Match straattankstation = match2.Match(nawhtml);
                Console.WriteLine("Straat       : " + straattankstation.Groups[1].Value);

                Regex match3 = new Regex(@"[^\(]*<br>\s*(.+?)\s*<br>");
                Match postcodetankstation = match3.Match(nawhtml);
                Console.WriteLine("Postcode     : " + postcodetankstation.Groups[1].Value);

                //Console.WriteLine("naw          : " + nawhtml);


                Console.WriteLine("Brandstof    : " + brandstof);
                Console.WriteLine("Prijs        : " + prijs);
                Console.WriteLine("Datum        : " + datum);
                Console.WriteLine(makeSpace);

                Console.WriteLine(makeSpace);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Database Code:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

var conn = new SqlDbConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = 
              "Data Source=ServerName;" + 
              "Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;" + 
              "User id=UserName;" + 
              "Password=Secret;"; 
conn.Open();
```

Can somebody give me a example, how I send the Console.Writeline strings to an SQL table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ServerName;" + 
          "Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;" + 
          "User id=UserName;" + 
          "Password=Secret;"))
{
    connection.Open();
    string sql =  "INSERT INTO Address(Naam,Straat,Postcode) VALUES(@param1,@param2,@param3)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,connection);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).value = naamtankstation.Groups[1].Value; 
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@param2", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).value = straattankstation.Groups[1].Value;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@param3", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).value = postcodetankstation.Groups[1].Value;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: This approach will work. Just use varchar max instead of fix length.